# How access to display device in embedded-linux + Qt ? /dev/fb0 not found

Tags: qt, embedded-linux, display, framebuffer

1-I have built Qt5.4.1 and Qt4.8.4 for an embedded device (based on armv5tejl) and all things work except GUI.

2-It seems that no frame buffer device exists:

```
~/bin $ ls -alh /dev/
drwxr-xr-x    3 0        sandbox        0 Nov 10 11:48 .
drwxr-xr-x   14 0        root           0 Nov 14  2017 ..
srw-rw-rw-    1 0        root           0 Nov 10 11:48 log
crw-rw-rw-    1 0        root        1,   3 Nov 10 11:48 null
crw-rw-rw-    1 0        root        5,   2 Nov 10 12:10 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x    2 0        root           0 Jan  1  1970 pts
crw-rw-rw-    1 0        root        5,   0 Nov 10 11:48 tty
crw-rw-rw-    1 0        root      204,  66 Nov 10 12:05 ttyAMA2
crw-r--r--    1 0        root        1,   9 Nov 10 11:48 urandom
```

---

```
/proc $ cat devices 
Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  7 vcs
 10 misc
/proc $ cat devices 
Character devices:
  1 mem
  4 /dev/vc/0
  4 tty
  5 /dev/tty
  5 /dev/console
  5 /dev/ptmx
  7 vcs
 10 misc
 13 input
 21 sg
 29 fb
 89 i2c
 90 mtd
100 softkey
116 alsa
122 pman
128 ptm
136 pts
150 pwmr
153 upc
154 kdrv_csc
180 usb
189 usb_device
204 ttyAMA
254 rtc

Block devices:
  1 ramdisk
259 blkext
  8 sd
 31 mtdblock
 65 sd
 66 sd
 67 sd
 68 sd
 69 sd
 70 sd
 71 sd
128 sd
129 sd
130 sd
131 sd
132 sd
133 sd
134 sd
135 sd
```

3-from dmesg log:

```
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 80x30
CLCD: PL110 CLCD hardware, HIE AT-T050QGH-02, VGA Landscape (supports 640x480 @ 24Mhz) display
```

4-Device itself has a SDK and display things using that SDK and libs in HTML format.

5-I have a restricted user on the device and I'm using my own BusyBox v1.20.0.

My Questions:

1-Is it possible for me to use device display via Qt without using provided SDK?

2-How could I access to the display device?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you very much